# Why remesher in sculpt mode always result many missing faces?

Tags: remesh

I'm sculpting a hijab.

Why remesher in sculpt mode always result many missing faces?

The settings:
[image]

How to fix this?
[image]

Comment: non-manifold geometry?  Before you remesh, in edit mode select all vertices, type M and select _by distance_.  Then recalculate normals by typing SHIFT-N.  Does that help?  If not which remesher are you using and what settings do you have?

Comment: Still the same. I add new image for the settings I use.